# Maintain scrolling speed on reloading table

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am working on a chat app. Initially I fetch only 100 message. As the user scroll table and reach to 9th message I fetch the another 100 message and reload the table.

To maintain the scroll position I set the content offset manually using `-setContentOffset:` method. Everything is working fine except scrolling speed. On reloading the table , table scrolling gets stopped.

How to maintain the scrolling speed?

Comment: don't load the messages on the main-thread, that would not block the UI.

Comment: I am not loading the message on main thread.

Comment: As @holex mentioned, it seems that there is a a process unrelated to updating the UI is running on the main thread...

Comment: threading is not the issue.  -setContentOffset: is the issue. To maintain the scrolling position I am using  -setContentOffset: method that cause scrolling to get stopped.

Comment: Couldn't you use `tableView.scrollToRow()` instead of `setContentOffset()`?

Comment: That will to will stop the scrolling. I want implementaion to be in such a way that user don't know that paging is implemented.